# How to set constantSize when creating StateListDrawable programmatically?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm creating a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) programmatically for the background for one of my custom views. In order for the the drawable to function correctly, [`constantSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3aconstantSize) needs to be set to true. When creating a `StateListDrawable`, this is just an XML attribute, but it doesn't look like this property is exposed in the class. I've worked around this with the following code:

```
StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
((DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState) drawable.getConstantState()).setConstantSize(true);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: may be drawable.setContantState(...) with constant state matching what you want. but then you may loose some info in the process

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the guess, but that method doesn't exist that I can see.

Comment: statelistdrawable extends drawablecontainer, which has a setconstantstate method

Comment: @njzk2 Ah, I see now. It's a protected method and at the moment, I'm not extending `StateListDrawable`.